# clock using fflush is not clearing screen

Tags: c, time, fflush

I am trying to make a clock in C, but the screen is not properly clearing, it just keeps printing to a new line. How am I improperly using `fflush`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    while (1) {

        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;

        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        printf ("%s", asctime (timeinfo));
        fflush(stdout);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fflushfflush just ensures that whatever you write to stdoutstdout is actually visible. It has nothing to do with clearing the screen. You could try prepending the string with `\r` to rewrite the output on the same line.

Comment: If you want to clear the screen, you need to write code to clear the screen. C doesn't assume you have a screen or that it can be cleared, so you will have to do it the way that is right for the particular platform or terminal that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strips out the newline from the asctime string and then uses a return to push the cursor back to the start of line

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        while (1) {

                    time_t rawtime;
                    char st[30];
                            struct tm * timeinfo;

                                    time ( &rawtime );
                                    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
                                    sprintf (st,"%s", asctime (timeinfo));
                                    *(index(st,'\n'))='\0';
                                    printf("\r%s",st);
                                    flush(stdout);
                                    sleep(1);

                  }
                                    return 0;
}
```

Comment: needs `index(st,'\n')`.  ?

Answer (score 2):

This one has the advantage that it will work from the current location on the screen, no matter what that is.  I added a label to print "The time is: " in order to show this. It does this by back spacing from the end of the time string rather than going to an absolute screen position or column.  Caveat: The hack to get sleep() under Visual C has not been tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #include <windows.h>
  #define sleep(T) Sleep((T) * 1000)
#else
  #include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main(void)
{
  char buf[42];
  time_t the_time[1];
  int i, len;

  printf("The time is: ");
  for (;;) {
    time(the_time);
    len = strlen(strcpy(buf, asctime(localtime(the_time)))) - 1;
    printf("%.*s", len, buf);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) putchar('\b'); 
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, looks portable between Windows and Unix/Linux too?

Comment: @ryyker I think so.  But I don't have Linux handy.  Windows cmd and mingw bash both work.

Comment: Yes, nice. And it also works on Linux, but warns about the "*implicit decalration*" of `sleep()`, as `unistd.h` is needed on Linux. However, why not use `'\b'` instead of `'\x08'`? Might read a bit more intuitive.

Comment: @alk Thanks.  Was typing fast and could not remember if `\b` is an escape in C.  Too many languages...  Also think the header warning is fixed.  In mingw I did not get the warning.  When I compiled with -Wall I got it even with unistd.h included. Hate this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...  (uses an evil windows call `SetConsoleCursorPosition()`, but does the trick)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y); 

int main()
{
    while (1) {

        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        gotoxy(0,0);//set to the upper left hand corner
        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        printf ("%s", asctime (timeinfo));
        fflush(stdout);

    }
    return 0;
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y) 
{ 
    COORD pos = {x, y};
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
}
```

Try this for POSIX:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcc -run
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
int main ()
{
    struct termios ts0, ts1;
    char cls [FILENAME_MAX];
    FILE *f;
    f = popen ("tput clear", "r");
    fgets (cls, FILENAME_MAX, f);
    pclose (f);
    tcgetattr (0, &ts0);
    ts1 = ts0;
    ts1.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    ts1.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr (0, TCSAFLUSH, &ts1);
    fputs (cls, stdout);
    while (1) putchar (getchar ());
    tcsetattr (0, TCSAFLUSH, &ts0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not have windows,  but I think that ncurses might have something similar.

Comment: Could not tell from the tags what system you were using, but yes, (n)curses for unix'esk stuff may do the trick.  Sorry I could not help :)

Comment: Your answer did provide me with an alternative way of solving the problem, Thanks, also my system is Mac and android.